# Can't update my inventory table with array laravel

Tags: laravel, database, function, migration, schema

I have an array list of data I want to update to the inventory table.

```
              $data['items'] = DB::table('inventory_items')->select('inventory_items.*')
                ->join('sorder_parts', 'inventory_items.id', 'sorder_parts.inventory_id')
                ->where('sorder_parts.sorder_id', '=', $id)
                ->selectraw('inventory_items.quantity - sorder_parts.quantity AS new_quantity')
                ->get()->toArray();

            foreach ($data as $product_item) {
                $reduce_quantity = InventoryItem::updateOrCreate(['id' => $product_item['items']['id']],
                ['quantity' => $product_item['quantity']['new_quantity']]);      
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$data['items'] = DB::table('inventory_items')
    ->select('inventory_items.*')
    ->join('sorder_parts', 'inventory_items.id', '=', 'sorder_parts.inventory_id')
    ->where('sorder_parts.sorder_id', '=', $id)
    ->selectRaw('inventory_items.id, inventory_items.quantity - sorder_parts.quantity AS new_quantity')
    ->get();

foreach ($data['items'] as $product_item) {
    InventoryItem::updateOrCreate(
        ['id' => $product_item->id], // Use $product_item->id instead of $product_item['items']['id']
        ['quantity' => $product_item->new_quantity] // Use $product_item->new_quantity instead of $product_item['quantity']['new_quantity']
    );
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, I appreciate this from the bottom of my heart.

Comment: no issues, glad to know it worked

Answer (score 0):

Probably $product_item variable does not have items key. Try to change "$product_item['items']['id']" to "$product_item['id']".

Because "DB" facade with get() method does not return a deep array.

Comment: still did not work,throws an error undefined array key "items"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't define `$fillable` property in the `InventoryItem` model.

So first of all, check your model and make sure you defined `$fillable` in it.

If it's defined, try debugging `$reduce_quantity` using the `dd()` or `Log::info()` function like below,

```
foreach ($data as $product_item) {
    $reduce_quantity = InventoryItem::updateOrCreate(['id' => $product_item['items']['id']],
         ['quantity' => $product_item['quantity']['new_quantity']]);     
    Log::info($reduce_quantity);
}
```

check your log file and see what the output is.